# Mobile web Google Maps directions link without GPS

Tags: google-maps

When I load the URL:

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/m/local?q=51.564666,+-3.275084
```

with a user agent string of:

```
Nokia9210i/1.0 Symbian Crystal/6.0
```

it gives a link saying "Get directions" but when I click on that nothing happens. I'd like the user to be able to enter a location for which Maps will generate the directions.

Is that possible?